# For loop with variable ending integer

Tags: vba, excel

I have a dataset of 40,000 rows of data. My code is set so that it checks if the date in row n+1 is 1 day after the date in row n. If the dates in rows n and n+1 do not follow in normal chronological order, then it adds a row with blank data for that date.

My issues is that because I am adding rows along as I go, I have no idea what the ending range my for loop should have. I also tried just setting a really large range like "For n = 2 to 50000". But this gives me an overflow error.

Here is my code:

```
Sub MissingDates()

Dim n As Integer

Worksheets("sheet1").Activate

For n = 2 To 40000
       If Cells(n, 2).Value <> Cells(n + 1, 2).Value - 1 Then
            Cells(n + 1, 2).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlShiftDown
            Cells(n + 1, 2) = Cells(n, 2) + 1
       End If
Next

End Sub
```

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: `Dim n As long` and `For n = cells(rows.coun, "B").end(xlup).row - 1 To 2 step-1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A signed integer does not reach 40,000 and you should work from the bottom up.

```
Option Explicit

Sub MissingDates()
    Dim n As Long, m As Long

    With Worksheets("sheet1")
        For n = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row - 1 To 2 Step -1
            For m = .Cells(n + 1, "B").Value2 - 1 To .Cells(n, "B").Value2 + 1 Step -1
                .Cells(n + 1, 2).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlShiftDown
                .Cells(n + 1, 2) = m
            Next m
        Next n
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I like how you incorporate the last row into the For n loop, Can you explain how the For m loop compares the values, I take it has something to do with the "To".

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly. I'm also curious how the "To" works to compare the m values. I didn't know "To" could be used in this way.

Comment: Dates are just numbers. The For m = ... to ... simply works from one date to the next, filling in any missing dates. If the dates are sequential the maths do not enter the For loop at all.

Answer (score 3):

The overflow error comes because you declare `n As Integer` (i.e. 32,767) but you push it until 40,000. You can solve that by declaring `n As Long` instead.

As for your problem, you rather want a `While` loop instead of a `For` one. It should look something like this:

```
n = 2 '<- your starting value
Do While Cells(n+1,2).Value <> "" '<-- I guess you stop when there's no more value in your row
       If Cells(n, 2).Value <> Cells(n + 1, 2).Value - 1 Then
            Cells(n + 1, 2).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlShiftDown
            Cells(n + 1, 2) = Cells(n, 2) + 1
       End If
       n = n + 1 '<-- increment n 
Loop
```