# Microsoft Excel inserting blank rows for missing time values

Tags: excel, function, excel-formula, excel-2010, vba

I have a set of time values in an Excel sheet. The following is a sample  similar to the data set that I have:

```
08:52:41
08:52:42
08:52:46
08:52:50
08:52:53
08:52:55
08:52:56
08:52:57
08:52:59
08:53:00
```

I need to be able to identify the missing time sequence values and to insert a blank row whenever a missing value is encountered. A reading is supposed to be taken every second. Missing time values do not occur at a constant rate and are random in their occurrence.
Is there a simple way to fix this?

Thank you

Comment: Should there be a record for **every second** ?

Comment: @Gary'sStudent Yes the readings should be for every second.

Comment: [This response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49481020/for-loop-with-variable-ending-integer/49481127?noredirect=1#comment86141628_49481127) should be able to be reworked for time instead of dates.

Comment: Could you provide me with a sample code for this please? As I am not at all experienced with using VBA. @Jeeped

Comment: Ah! So you're really here just to phish out someone to write your code for free, Your question would be better if you posted it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?med=site-ui&ref=jobs-tab). If you don't want to do that then get started inserting rows and typing out times.

Comment: **Welcome to [so]!**  You might have the wrong idea about this site; [so] is a place for professional *(or enthusiast)* programmers to share advice when a problem's solution can't be found elsewhere. The best S.O. Questions have a bit of source code in them, but if your question covers a ***specific*** programming problem, algorithm, or software tool, **and** is a practical, answerable problem that is ***unique*** to software development, then you’re in the right place to ask your question!  Please see "[help/on-topic]" as well as "[ask]".

Comment: Well thanks a lot for being very useful :) @Jeeped